# Erasing in stdin all instances of regexes defined in a file

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I am after something like a combination of `sed 's/pattern//g'` and `grep -f patternfile.txt`.

Basically I would like the input stream to be stripped of all instances of the regex patterns defined in `patternfile.txt` (which contains one regex per line), so that

`cat myinitialfile.txt | magiccommands -f patternfile.txt > mycleanfile.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/^.*/s\/&\/\//' pattern > sed-pattern-file
sed -f sed-pattern-file myinitialfile.txt > mycleanfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As a variation on the answer already here - it is easier still, probably, to pull the script directly out of a pipe:

```
sed 's|.*|s/&//g|' <patterns |
sef -f - infile >outfile
```

That way you needn't alter the patterns file - or any other - directly and can instead modify it in-stream to suit your needs.